# Replacing an Excel connection range with an Add-In

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I've having a bit of a nightmare with an Excel Add-In I've written. The customers workbook used to be populated from a SQL connection and has loads of formulas setup around named tables etc. I'm trying to populate some the same tables that connection populated (using the existing headers and footers) with the data from a WCF service while maintaining formatting and formulas (ie: not break anything).

Getting the data in is fine. The problem I'm hitting is this: The data being replaced may be more or less data than currently exists in the named range. I can't seem to find a way of removing the exising rows and replacing them with my new data and having the named range resize to the new data.

Many thanks in advance.

```
Range range = activeWorksheet.get_Range("Name", MissingValue);
range.Clear();
object[,] data = new object[result.Length, 26];
range.get_Resize(result.Length, 26);
... fill data....
range.Value2 = data;
```

Comment: Can you give examples of the data you are working with, and an idea of what the spreadsheets look like?

Comment: Unfortunately the actual data is sensitive, but the problem is not with the data. It boils down to clearing a named range and populating it and making sure the named range is the correct size to fit the new data.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, managed to solve it with the code below. Also removed the "range.Clear()" call which stopped the formatting from being removed.

```
 Range range = activeWorksheet.get_Range("Name", MissingValue);
 int totalMissingRows = 0;
            if (range.Rows.Count < result.Length)
            {
                totalMissingRows = result.Length - range.Rows.Count;
                for (int i = 0, l = totalMissingRows; i < l; i++)
                {

                    Excel.Range rng = range;
                    rng = (Excel.Range)rng.Cells[rng.Rows.Count, 1];
                    rng = rng.EntireRow;
                    rng.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, MissingValue);
                }
            }

            //delete extra lines
            //remove left over data
            for (int i = result.Length, l = range.Rows.Count; i < l; i++) { range.Cells[range.Rows.Count, 1].EntireRow.Delete(null); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are already getting an array of data, why not directly write it to the excel like this:
`int startRow, startCol;`
`var startCell = (Range)worksheet.Cells[startRow, startCol];

var endCell = (Range)worksheet.Cells[startRow + result.Length, startCol + 26];

var writeRange = worksheet.get_Range(startCell, endCell);

writeRange.Value2 = data;`

Here, I have used the lengths of your array as per your question and data is the 2d array of data.